# How to turn a keyup event into a click button using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a input field with a working keyup event, and I need to turn the icon into a button, so when the user clicks on it, it applies the filter. This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text"
 matInput
 (keyup)="applyFilterOrgReach($event.target.value, countries, 500)"
 (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
  <i class="fas fa-search search-icon"></i>
```

And my component.ts:

```
applyFilterOrgReach(filterValue: string, values: MatTableDataSource<any[]>, debounceTime: number) {
    this.organizationReachSearchParam = filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (filterValue === null) {
        values.filter = '';
      } else {
        values.filter = this.organizationReachSearchParam;
      }
      this.globalRegions = this.getGlobalRegions(this.countries.filteredData);
    }, debounceTime);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the input value in click event and use the existing method in ts same as yours.

```
<input type="text"
     matInput #input
     (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
      <i class="fas fa-search search-icon" (click)="applyFilterOrgReach(input.value, countries, 500)"></i>
```

Comment: When I try this, the organizationReachSearchParam and the filterValue.trim come as undefined, so the event doesn't work. I think that they are only receiving what's being typed on the keyup, but I don't know if that's truly the problem or how I can fix it

Comment: @AgathaGarcia Please remove keydown event and try once

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried it now and it worked! Thank you!